# How to send additional data to the laravel.log file?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I'm getting some error messages in the laravel.log file, but the error description doesn't help me to find the problem. I want to register some extra data, to be specific, the `request URL` and the `request data`, in all the errors reported to the log file. How can I add those two things?

```
[2015-11-09 13:30:01] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:2888
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9464): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /app/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9464): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12789): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9464): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11412): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9464): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12530): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9464): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9454): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2209): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#17 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2192): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 {main}
```

Comment: You want to find the error or record the errors ?

Comment: Record the URL and the request data of when the error occurred. The current info in the error description ins't enough to find where the problem was originated.

Comment: Then you should do try catch and record the exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` modify the `public function report(Exception $e)`.

```
// ...
use Request;

// ...
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if ($this->shouldReport($e)) {
        $request = Request::all();

        $this->log->error("request url: " . Request::url());
        $this->log->error("request data: " . json_encode($request));
    }

    parent::report($e);
}
```

Finally, the reported error in laravel.log will contain the request URL and data.

```
[2015-11-12 03:41:14] local.ERROR: request url: http://example.com/path  
[2015-11-12 03:41:14] local.ERROR: request data: {"key":"value"}
[2015-11-12 03:41:14] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:2888
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9464): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /app/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9464): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12789): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#7 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9464): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11412): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9464): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12530): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9464): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9454): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2209): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#17 /bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2192): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 {main}
```

Comment: Did you find the root of the problem? I'm having this too on a production app.

Comment: Check if request token is being sent. If it is, ad session data as I did with the request data. Compare if request token matches the session token.

Comment: I think this will add the additional information only for error exceptions, if you call `\Log::error('some error');` or `\Log::info('some info');` it will not drop in `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php@report` method to add those additional information to log

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you have `TokenMismatchException`

**How can i fix it**

You can fix it by sending the `_token` that is generated by Laravel.

You can get the `_token` by default in your form if you use Form Helper, if not you can do it manually by passing it as hidden

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

**Note :**

By default Laravel will record all the errors in .log file inside storage/logs/laravel-date.log.

If you want to record those logs in then you need to do try catch and record manually inside db.

Comment: The TokenMismatchException is threw internally in the Laravel framework. I do have implement csrf_token() already. Seems as one page some where in some form is not doing it well. The info provided by the error description doesn't allow me to know where that form, page or line of code is. Knowing the URL and the request data of the error will help me find it.

Comment: Ok, can't u check on all forms ?

Comment: I understand this is a TokenMismatchException. I have checked the forms already and all seems to be fine. Also, have run all the tests and everything seems fine again. The site has many visits and for some users in a specific context this exception is being threw. That's why I want to know the URL and the request they are sending.

Comment: I will modify the exception handler for the VerifyCsrfToken middleware.

Comment: Are you going to remove the handler from middleware. If so then it will make your app less secured.

Comment: The report method inside the ExceptionHandler seems to do the trick. `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`. I'm now looking at it how to customise the report.

Comment: No, not removing it, I want to fix the problem, not to hide it.

Comment: Good, look on the `app/Http/VerifyCsrfToken` , inside the function `public function handle($request, Closure $next)` You can also customize it for your need there :)

Comment: Thanks, I was just in there before, thats the middleware handler, but not the error one. It is in `public function report(Exception $e)` at `ExceptionHandler` located in `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

Comment: That's great :) +1 for your interest :)